# How can I force components to re-render without using props or state directly in JSX?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Consider the 3 following JS files (index.js, actions.js and reducer.js) in a react-native application using **react-redux**.

> index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {onSetup} from './actions';

class Scene01 extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {

        // dataFromOtherScene EXISTS when this Scene is created!
        // It is an OBJECT;

        this.props.onSetup(this.props.dataFromOtherScene);

    }

    render () {

        console.log('R', this.props);

        if ((this.props.paths) && (this.props.reference) && (this.props.current >= 0)) {

            const processedData = this.props.reference[Object.keys(this.props.reference)[0]].data;

            const currentPath = this.props.path[this.props.current];

            const pathData = processedData.steps[currentPath[1]].questions[currentPath[2]];

            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{currentPath.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{pathData.anyProperty}</Text>
                    <Text>{pathData.anotherProperty}</Text>
                </View>
            );

        } else {

            return (
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
            );

        }

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        ...state.Scene01Reducer,
        dataFromOtherScene: state.OtherScene.data
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    onSetup
})(Scene01);
```

> actions.js

```
export const ON_SETUP_SUCCESS_ACTION = 'D8129820-723B-42CE-9C2D-EA0524919E89';
export const onSetup = (data) => {

    const paths = [];
    const reference = data.reference[Object.keys(data.reference)[0]].steps;

    const steps = Object.keys(reference);

    for (let s = 0; s < steps.length; s++) {

        const step = reference[steps[s]];

        const path = [step.title, steps[s]];

        const questions = Object.keys(step.questions);

        for (let q = 0; q < questions.length; q++) {

            const fullpath = [...path, questions[q]];

            paths.push(fullpath);

        }

    }

    return {
        type: ON_SETUP_SUCCESS_ACTION,
        payload: {paths, reference}
    };

};
```

> reducer.js

```
import {ON_SETUP_SUCCESS_ACTION} from './actions';

/**
 * Default State
 */
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    current: null,
    paths: null,
    reference: null
};

/**
 * Reducer Body
 */
export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ON_SETUP_SUCCESS_ACTION:
            return {...state, paths: action.payload.paths, reference: action.payload.reference, current: 0};
        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

I tried many approaches... constructor, componentWillReceiveProps, componentShouldUpdate but after the react-redux updates the state (`return {type: ON_SETUP_SUCCESS_ACTION, payload: {paths, reference}};`), the render method is called again but the `} else {` statement keeps rendered.

The `console.log('R', this.props);` shows the first time it is called **null** for the 3 reducers properties: *paths*, *reference* and *current*.

The second time, after reducer update, the console shows these 3 properties properlly set... but the component does not update... does not re-render.

Answer (score 2):

are you completely sure that your if is with a true value?

(this.props.paths) && (this.props.reference) && (this.props.current >= 0) this could be false and the else statement would always render.

If it is, you could try to use a lifecycle method like componentWillMount or componentWillUpdate.

**Also i think that you should use mapStateToProps to send paths, reference and current as a prop.**

Comment: Yep! I checked in console the conditional. I saw, the second time console.log is called, all the properties properly set. I really think that is something concerning the lifecycle... something related to async behavior. I might missed something... 'cause I tried these 2 methods you suggested.

Comment: So it worked to put paths, reference and current inside mapStateToProps?

Comment: Yep! It worked! When I submited my answer, yours showed up too, suggesting the same approach I used. Thanks for you contribution!

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I decided to move all the "onSetup" code from actions to `const mapStateToProps` scope and then I remove all react-native component* methods. As I need a start, I removed the **paths** and **reference** from the reducer and set then directly in *mapStateToProps* scope:

> index.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const paths = [];
    const reference = data.reference[Object.keys(data.reference)[0]].steps;

    const steps = Object.keys(reference);

    for (let s = 0; s < steps.length; s++) {
    ...


    return {
        ...state.Scene01Reducer,
        dataFromOtherScene: state.OtherScene.data,
        paths,
        reference
    };

};
```

> reducer.js

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    current: 0,
};
```

> actions.js

`Deleted!`

This worked for me as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After going through what you need, I think you should try `forceUpdate()` function which re-renders the component without using setState.

Comment: I tried with no success, @Codesingh. This was my approach: 

    `componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
         if ((this.props.current !== nextProps.current)) {
          this.forceUpdate(() => {
       console.log('Test!');
      });
         }
        }`

Test is showed in console... but component did not re-render. I'll keep looking. Must be something "out of the box".